# How to extract a source package?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, 16.04

I have a source package:

apt-get source -y gcc-4.9-multilib

I want to extract it:

```
#dpkg-source -x gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc

dpkg-source: warning: extracting unsigned source package (gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.dsc)
dpkg-source: info: extracting gcc-4.9 in gcc-4.9-4.9.2
dpkg-source: info: unpacking gcc-4.9_4.9.2.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: applying gcc-4.9_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~12.04.diff.gz
```

The extracted folder doesn't contents the sources:

```
#ls gcc-4.9-4.9.2/
debian  gcc-4.9.2.tar.xz  gdc-20141020.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have there now two tar archives which you can extract with:

```
tar -xf gcc-4.9.2.tar.xz
tar -xf gdc-20141020.tar.xz
```